# Python Pandas grouping columns without aggregating

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. Username, email and membership. I want to group by membership.

Input dataframe look like this:

```
abc1 abc@company.com prod1
abc1 abc@company.com prod2
abc1 abc@company.com prod3
def1 def@company.com prod2
def1 def@company.com prod3
xyz1 xyz@company.com prod1
xyz1 xyz@company.com prod3
xyz1 xyz@company.com prod4
```

Output I want is:

```
abc1  abc@company.com prod1
                      prod2
                      prod3
def1  def@company.com prod2
                      prod3
xyz1  xyz@company.com prod1
                      prod3
                      prod4
```

I tried this but can't seem to get around without using aggregate function

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['Members'])
dn_group = df.groupby(['username','email'])
new_df  = dn_group['membership'].agg('value_counts')
print(new_df)
```

Here is what I get:

```
username  email           membership 
abc1      abc@company.com prod1        1
                          prod2        1
                          prod3        1
def1  def@company.com     prod2        1
                          prod3        1
xyz1  xyz@company.com     prod1        1
                          prod3        1
                          prod4        1
```

Basically, I do not want to get the last column with the counts.

`

Comment: What difference does it make between your input and output? I think you don't need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "username": ['abc1','abc1','abc1','def1','def1','xyz1','xyz1','xyz1'],
    "email":['abc@company.com','abc@company.com','abc@company.com','def@company.com','def@company.com','xyz@company.com','xyz@company.com','xyz@company.com'],
    'membership':['prod1','prod2','prod3','prod2','prod3','prod1','prod3','prod4'] })
df.groupby(['username','email'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: set(x))
```

Result:

```
username    email            membership
0   abc1    abc@company.com  {prod2, prod3, prod1}
1   def1    def@company.com  {prod2, prod3}
2   xyz1    xyz@company.com  {prod4, prod3, prod1}
```

Comment: Thanks Code Pope.  It worked as I expected. I just added few lines to make username and email an index and also aligned all the columns on same line and converted set values to string.                                                                     dn_group = df.groupby(['Username','Email'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x:("/".join(sorted(set(x)))))
dn_group.set_index(['Username','Email'],inplace=True)
final_result = dn_group.reset_index().to_string(index=False)
print(final_result)